# Julia: find maximum along columns in array

Tags: julia

Suppose we have an array defined like this:

```
a=[1 2; 3 4; 5 5; 7 9; 1 2];
```

In Matlab, we could find the maximum values by writing:

```
 [x y] = max(a)
   x =
     7     9
```

In Julia, we could use:

```
  a=[1 2; 3 4; 5 5; 7 9; 1 2]
  findmax(a,1)
```

returning:

```
 ([7 9],

  [4 9])
```

However, I am interested not only in finding [7 9] for the two columns, but also their relative position within each column, like [4, 4]. Of course, I can write a bit more of coding lines, but can I do it directly with findmax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second matrix returned by `findmax` is the *linear* index of the locations of the maxima over the entire array.  You want the position within each column; to get that, you can convert the linear indices into subscripts with `ind2sub`.  Then the first element of the subscript tuple is your row index.

```
julia> vals, inds = findmax(a, 1)
(
[7 9],

[4 9])

julia> map(x->ind2sub(a, x), inds)
1×2 Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},2}:
 (4,1)  (4,2)

julia> map(x->ind2sub(a, x)[1], inds)
1×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 4  4
```

Comment: This is changing in the upcoming version 0.7 — `findmax` will return `CartesianIndex` objects directly, making it much easier to access the column and row indices.

Comment: that's great news!

Answer (score 2):

This is mentioned in the comments but I figured I'd do a response that's easy to see. I have version 1.0.3, so I don't know what's the earliest version that allows this. But now you can just do

```
julia> findmax(a) #Returns 2D index of overall maximum value
(9, CartesianIndex(4, 2))

julia> findmax(a[:,1]) #Returns 1D index of max value in column 1
(7, 4)

julia> findmax(a[:,2]) #Returns 1D index of max value in column 2
(9, 4)
```

Hope this makes things easier.

Answer (score 0):

I've adopted the following function:

```
indmaxC(x) = cat(1, [indmax(x[:,c]) for c in 1:size(x,2)]...)
```

- The Good: it's convenient and small
- The Bad: it's only valid for 2-D arrays

A safer version would be:

```
function indmaxC(x::AbstractArray)
    assert(ndims(x)==2)
    cat(1, [indmax(x[:,c]) for c in 1:size(x,2)]...)
end
```

Comment: Nice approach.  Try: `indmaxC(x) = mapslices(indmax, x, 1)`.  It's effectively the same idea, but should be simpler, faster, and more general.